Different folders for image and pdf
In media settings, you can use different folders for images and files. I set to images - "image" folder and for pdf - "public" folder. But, when I upload a PDF to the site, the file is uploaded to the "image" folder.
How to change the pdf download path to the correct folder?

You need to update the FileSystem Local Plugin and add another entry for your 'public' folder for your files. The extra folders will then appear on the left of your Media page that you can select as the destination for your uploads.
https://docs.joomla.org/Special:MyLanguage/J4.x:Media:_Options
